# Как положить предмет на ящик и как его обратно взять персонажу в руки в 3D

Tags: unity3d

Первоначально делал через создание-удаление объекта, но наткнулся на проект в открытом доступе, который делает то что я хочу, но в 2Д. [Проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/95gncxrdji9jsfv/Farm%20Alarm%20Source.zip?dl=0).

В целом, как я понял идея в том что мы через *ScriptableObject* меняем спрайт на столе через слой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**p.s.** Что собой представляет OverlaySprite, пустой объект? Почему он как префаб, но серый, хотя он активный.

Основной код:

**CropAsset:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Crop", menuName = "Crop")]
public class CropAsset : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite seedSprite;
    public Sprite deadSprite;
    public Sprite doneSprite;

    public bool seedIsOnGround = false;
}
```

**Crop:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Crop
{
    public CropAsset asset;

    public CropState state;

    private float growthLevel;
    private float waterLevel;
    private bool isDead;

    public bool Grow(float amount)
    {
        if (GetWaterState() == WaterState.Watered)
        {
            growthLevel += amount / 20f;
        }

        if (growthLevel >= 1f)
        {
            state = CropState.Done;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public WaterState Dry(float amount)
    {
        waterLevel -= amount / 8f;
        return GetWaterState();
    }

    public WaterState GetWaterState ()
    {
        if (waterLevel > 0f)
        {
            return WaterState.Watered;
        }
        else if (waterLevel > -1f)
        {
            return WaterState.Dry;
        }
        else
        {
            state = CropState.Dead;
            return WaterState.Dead;
        }
    }

    public void Water ()
    {
        waterLevel = 1f;
    }

    public Crop (CropAsset a) {
        asset = a;
        state = CropState.Seed;
        growthLevel = 0f;
        waterLevel = 1f;
        isDead = false;
    }

    public bool HasCrop()
    {
        if (asset == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Sprite GetCropSprite()
    {
        if (asset == null)
            return null;

        switch (state)
        {
            case CropState.Seed:
                return asset.seedSprite;
            case CropState.Planted:
                return asset.seedSprite;
            case CropState.Dead:
                return asset.deadSprite;
            case CropState.Done:
                return asset.doneSprite;
        }

        Debug.LogError("WHAT?!");
        return asset.seedSprite;
    }

    public bool IsOnGround()
    {
        if (state == CropState.Planted && asset.seedIsOnGround)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public Sprite GetDoneSprite()
    {
        return asset.doneSprite;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        if (asset == null)
            return null;

        return asset.name;
    }
}

public enum CropState
{
    Seed,
    Planted,
    Dead,
    Done
}

public enum WaterState
{
    Watered,
    Dry,
    Dead
}
```

**Tool:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Tool", menuName = "Tool")]
public class Tool : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite sprite;
    public ToolType toolType;
}

public enum ToolType
{
    Plow,
    Watercan
}
```

**TableTile:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TableTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer overlay;

    public Crop crop;
    public Tool tool;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (crop.HasCrop())
            overlay.sprite = crop.GetCropSprite();
        else if (tool != null)
            overlay.sprite = tool.sprite;
    }

    public void Interact(Crop c, Tool t, PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        player.SetCrop(crop);
        crop = c;
        player.SetTool(tool);
        tool = t;

        if (tool != null)
            overlay.sprite = tool.sprite;
        else if (crop != null)
            overlay.sprite = crop.GetCropSprite();
        else
            overlay.sprite = null;
    }

}
```

Хочу сделать также, но для 3Д объектов. Мне порекомендовали поменять там где используется Sprite и SpriteRenderer на Mesh и MeshRenderer.

Мой код:

**IngredientAsset:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Ingredient", menuName = "Ingredient")]
public class IngredientAsset : ScriptableObject {

    public Mesh ingredientMesh;

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ingredient:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Ingredient : MonoBehaviour {

    public IngredientAsset asset;

    public Ingredient (IngredientAsset a) {
        asset = a;
    }

    public bool HasIngrediend()
    {
        if (asset == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Mesh GetIngrediendObject()
    {
        if (asset == null)
            return null;

        return asset.ingredientMesh;

    }
}
```

**EquipmentAsset:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Equipment", menuName = "Equipment")]
public class EquipmentAsset : ScriptableObject {

    public Mesh equipmentMesh;

}
```

**TableBox:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TableBox : MonoBehaviour {

    public MeshRenderer overlay;

    public Ingredient ingredient;
    public EquipmentAsset equipment;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (ingredient.HasIngrediend())
            overlay.mesh = ingredient.GetIngrediendObject();
        else if (equipment != null)
            overlay.mesh = equipment.mesh;
    }

    public void Interact(Ingredient c, EquipmentAsset t, PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        player.SetIngredient(ingredient);
        ingredient = c;
        player.SetEquipment(equipment);
        equipment = t;

        if (equipment != null)
            overlay.sprite = equipment.mesh;
        else if (ingredient != null)
            overlay.mesh = ingredient.GetIngrediendObject();
        else
            overlay.mesh = null;
    }
}
```

Но начиная с момента создания моих ScriptableObjects типа mesh, в моей версии ***Crop***
ругается на ***overlay.mesh***.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам стол:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Overlay:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Прошу помочь разобраться как преобразовать данную функцию к 3Д объектам. Правильно ли то что мне подсказали? Правильно ли так делать? Можно также но с префабами?

Comment: Вы приложите, что **вы уже переписали** и где конкретно появляется **ошибка**. "моей версии Crop ругается на overlay.mesh" - это не описание проблемы.

Comment: OverlaySprite - это, по всей видимости, объект для отрисовки, логика находится в родительском объекте.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker как я упоминал выше, особо ничего не менял кроме меш, меш рендер. Но мне так посоветовали. Добавил информацию по вашей просьбе, + скриншоты. p.s. Почему в 2д проекте в скрипте TableTile в поле Crop ложится объект типа CropAsset, а у меня(я вроде делаю также). в поле Ingredient не ложится IngredientAsset (разные типы, но у 2д проекта же получается). Возможно что-то упустил из виду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала стоит пояснить, что `ScriptableObject` - это некого рода контейнер или, вернее, **обертка над какими-то ресурсами**, который можно инстанциировать и вообще взаимодействовать с ним, как с объектом.

---

Теперь эта ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вся проблема в том, что `MeshRenderer` **не хранит меш, который рисует**, он получает ее от `MeshFilter`. В 2д со спрайтами этим всем занимается ровно 1 объект, с мешами это не так.

Решить проблему довольно просто - нужно хранить ссылку на `MeshFilter`, на `MeshRenderer` нам все равно:

```
public class TableBox : MonoBehaviour {

    public MeshFilter overlay;

    // ...

    private void Start()
    {
        if (ingredient.HasIngrediend())
            overlay.mesh = ingredient.GetIngrediendObject();
        else if (equipment != null)
            overlay.mesh = equipment.mesh;
    }

    public void Interact(Ingredient c, EquipmentAsset t, PlayerInteraction player)
    {
        // ...
        if (equipment != null)
            overlay.mesh = equipment.mesh;
        else if (ingredient != null)
            overlay.mesh = ingredient.GetIngrediendObject();
        else
            overlay.mesh = null;
    }
}
```

---

> Почему в 2д проекте в скрипте TableTile в поле Crop ложится объект
>   типа CropAsset, а у меня(я вроде делаю также). в поле Ingredient не
>   ложится IngredientAsset (разные типы, но у 2д проекта же получается).

Этого я вообще не понял, у вас поле ingredient имеет тип `Ingredient`, куда вы хотите положить объект типа `IngredientAsset`. Вот поэтому и не работает.

Comment: Насчёт последнего. => Я о том же! Посмотрите самый первый скриншот с 2д проекта. Там в поле отчётливо видно место для объекта типа CropAsset. Хотя в самом коде скрипта Table Tile - указан объект типа Crop. Чудеса?

Comment: Там все правильно написано: `Crop Asset`, у вас же `IngredientAsset` помещается в `Ingredient`, все закономерно не работает, никаких чудес.

Comment: Возможно в связи с  поздним часом я рассеянный. Но! Я понимаю, что я не могу положить объект типа ИнгредиентАссет в Ингредиет, но код из 2д же может? Вот [скрин](http://skrinshoter.ru/s/080219/yJaEiMuJ). Прошу прощение, если мой спор кажется вам глупым.

Comment: 2д код линкает `ScriptableObject` не в объект типа `Crop`, а в **поле объекта** типа 'Crop' - это 2 разные вещи.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А что если я хочу такое же с префабами делать? Или лучше создать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: Мой вам совет - лучше не надо делать это через префабы :) Префабы больше весят, вносят путаницу в файлы проекта и тому подобное, а как таковой дополнительный функционал они вам не дадут. В данном случае ну вот ничего не поменяется, будут это префабы или scriptable objects.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89449/discussion-between-artik-slayer-and-riotbr3aker).